# How can i set 3 columns gridline for responsive XML

Tags: android, xml, gridview

I need to use a 3 column gridview with gridline in a project. So, I have a result;

This is Note 3 result(5.7" and Version "4.4.2"); https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDzdg.jpg

This is Note 5 result(5.7" and Version "Android M"); https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeH0o.jpg

Here my codes;
**fragment_homepage.xml**

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#fff">

   <RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <GridView
            android:id="@+id/GVHomepage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="3"
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:background="#edf2f8" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/PBLoading"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleInverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

**categories_row.xml**

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:background="#fff">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TVCategoryName"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Yiyecek"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#745f87"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/IVCategoryPhoto"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/TVCategoryName"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

   </LinearLayout>
```

**So, How do I get the result like the "Note 3" at all screen resolutions?**

Comment: Check my posted code. It will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should create different [dimens](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) xmls for different screens and set the layout width and height of your RelativeLayout view of the file `categories_row.xml`

```
...
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="@dimen/box_width"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/box_height"
        android:background="#fff">
...
```

and your dimens.xml for note 3 will be like that

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="box_width">120dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="box_height">120dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

then you create another dimens.xml for different sizes

Comment: Hello @gmetax, so if i used 120dp for 1080x1920, how can i calculate for different screen size? I havent devices with different screen resolutions and i dont use Emulator.

Comment: to "see" you don't need an emulator but just the layout viewer and you can set the prefer sizes

Answer (score 0):

If you will combine **android:numColumns="auto_fit"**  and **android:stretchMode="columnWidth"** will give you a layout that adjusts for different screen sizes. Much better than fixing the number of columns. See  below.

```
<GridView
            android:id="@+id/GVHomepage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:numColumns="3" // you can also use auto_fit here to set according to screens
            android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
            android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:background="#edf2f8" />
```